# Проблема прописных букв

Tags: прописная-строчная

Почему *Верховный Суд РФ* пишется с большой буквы, а *мировой судья* - с маленькой?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что Верховный Суд РФ - это уникальное название, т.е. такое, которое обозначает единичное явление, объект и т.д. , а мировой судья - должность. Мы ведь не пишем, например, слово *директор* с прописной буквы, потому что директоров много. 
Кстати о Верховном Суде. В правилах русской орфографии и пунктуации под ред. В.В. Лопатина конкретно этого наименования нет, но, например, есть **Верховный суд США**, **Высший арбитражный суд РФ**. 
У Розенталя в этом словосочетании оба слова пишутся с прописной (См. Примечание 1 к §22 СПРАВОЧНИКА ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ: "*В соответствии с традицией* все слова в названиях высших государственных учреждений и общественных организаций России, а также бывшего Советского Союза пишутся с прописной буквы, например: Верховный Совет РФ, Совет Федерации, **Верховный Суд России**..."). А в Примечании 2 к этому же параграфу читаем: "Но в написании некоторых новых названий наблюдаются колебания, например: Федеральное **с**обрание (Федеральное **С**обрание), Государственная **д**ума (Государственная **Д**ума), Конституционный **с**уд (Конституционный **С**уд)". Так что не все так просто с судами.

Answer (score 0):

Второй Международный форум активных интернет-пользователей "Диалог культур" - это, скажем, полное официальное название.

Тогда Второй форум интернет-пользователей - можно считать неполным официальным названием и писать, следовательно, первое слово с прописной?

А Форум интернет-пользователей - как это название классифицировать: неполное официальное название или неофициальное название? И в этом втором случае писать со строчной: форум интернет-пользователей?

Короче говоря, я не нашла в литературе определения всем этим часто употребляемым словам "полное", "неполное", "неофициальное", "сокращенное", "усеченное" применительно к названию учреждений, мероприятий, должностей и так далее. Лишь насчет "официальное" пишется: как в установочных документах. Да приводятся, скажем, на "Грамоте" отдельные примеры типа Председатель Правительства Российской Федерации. А если  Беда особенно с названиями разных мероприятий. На что опираться?